Kasa smart switch two red wire and one yellow wire
Two red wire one yellow wire

Hi I try to replace the old switch to the kasa smart switch , the old one has two red wire and one yellow wire , there is another switch control the same light , my question is the yellow on the old switch is ground or it’s a switch leg , how should I wire them to the new switch

Ground is bare/green/or green with yellow stripes.  Yellow can be a hot/live colour or in your case a switch leg/traveller.  Before removing any wires, label them with what screws they go to.  Mixing up the two reds will make life more difficult.

In a close-up of the white-box-on-back switch, it appears there are two screws, Black = "Line" (power in) and Red = "Load" (power out to light). Also, there are a White wire, probably Neutral, and Green wire, probably ground.
The black-box-on-back switch has two red wires, one yellow wire, and a ground screw tab. It appears that the electrical system is conduit, with individual machine-printing-labeled conductors pulled through. If the previous electrician followed standard custom, the yellow wire would be the power in/out, and the red wires will be the travelers, either of which could be powered at any time. Neither yellow nor reds are ground: don't connect them as ground or sparks will be released.
The black box switch is apparently a 3-way switch, with another 3-way switch mating to this one somewhere else on the light circuit.
The white box switch is a standard on/off smart switch that controls a light solely by itself, not paired with another 3-way switch somewhere else.
You can't simply replace the 3-way black box switch with the new smart switch. Get a smart 3-way switch, which will have the common and two traveler screws, as well as neutral and ground.

Thank you , do I need two 3 way smart outlet switch both of them , or I can just change this one with one smart 3 way

You should only need one smart 3-way. Leave the other one "dumb" as it is now.
